# SharePoint List migration from MOSS to 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, migration, attachment

I have exported the SharePoint List from MOSS server to the network file system in to number of ".DAT" files (since the size of the List is huge) using the class [SPExport Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.spexport%28v=office.12%29.aspx). The code is same as mentioned in the MSDN ex. Next before importing, I have changed the SystemData.xml file with the current version of the SharePoint site where the List is supposed to be imported.

Now, I am trying to import the same data using the [SPImport Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.spimport(v=office.12).aspx). The code snippet is as follows:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") > $null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment") > $null

$settings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImportSettings

$settings.IncludeSecurity = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPIncludeSecurity]::All
$settings.UpdateVersions = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPUpdateVersions]::Overwrite 
$settings.UserInfoDateTime = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImportUserInfoDateTimeOption]::ImportAll

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($DestWebURL)
Write-Host "DestWebURL", $DestWebURL

$web = $site.OpenWeb()

Write-Host "SPWeb", $web.Url

$settings.SiteUrl = $web.Url
$settings.WebUrl = $web.Url
$settings.FileLocation = "C:\Piyush\FileLocation\"
$settings.BaseFileName = $FileName
$settings.LogFilePath = $LogFilePath
$settings.FileCompression = 1

Write-Host "FileLocation", $settings.FileLocation

$import = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport($settings)
$import.Run()

$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

The problem is that though it is running to completion and all the items also gets imported to the destination List, most of the attachments were not imported! When I checked the log, it shows for a number of attachments that "SomeName.DAT" file is not found. I am not able to figure out the reason behind this strange behavior. Though, the items are all there with the correct values for all of their Fields, the attachments are missing. Plz advice what can be done here.